# Is 'asked A of B' correct?

Tags: questions, direct-speech

Consider the following sentence I wrote myself:

> "If He is everywhere, then why is He not present before me in this pillar?" asked Hiranyakashyap of Prahlad.

Is this correct?

Or should I change it to:

> "If He is everywhere, then why is He not present before me in this pillar?" Hiranyakashyap asked Prahlad.

Comment: It's a "marked" (noticeably unusual)  literary / poetic construction. You should indeed change ***asked John of Jane*** to ***John asked Jane*** in all normal contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is perfectly correct. The second is more easily readable, but if you wanted the first for stylistic purposes then there is nothing wrong with it. This formation is less commonly used when describing direct speech, a more common usage would be something like "He did everything I asked of him.". In any case the "of" clearly references the person being asked.